# how to write Semantic correct html in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, create-react-app, semantic-markup

In a react webapp. In index.html the div with id="root" is present, which is then referenced to render APP)in react.
My understanding is that this root div is introducing non semantic nature in the webapp which will effect the SEO of the website. think of a header, main and footer in the parent div. All these should be directly inside the body tag, right?

How can we improve this?? If we can use fragment in place of div why it is not the default option which creating a new create-react-app??

Comment: Not using react but can't you move that id to the body?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `main` doesn't have to be directly inside `body` tag. Also, semantic tags are about accessibility rather than SEO.

Comment: @Dejan.S: Tried that however react discourage this. you get warning and it says the doing this can create reconciliation issues.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski:
[Does semantic tags help SEO?
Semantic HTML refers to syntax that makes the HTML more comprehensible by better defining the different sections and layout of web pages. It makes web pages more informative and adaptable, allowing browsers and search engines to better interpret content] - source - https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/semantic-html

it is not about being main directly inside the body. but suppose if you have a header, main and footer which should be in the body. but now due to react app. the semantic structure would be body->div(root)->(header : main : footer)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `div`s are ignored by tree parsers, but I'm not sure.  Side note: if you are worried about SEO, you should know that single-page applications work really bad with crawlers. You should consider using server-side rendering.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski: Yes I am aware the SPAs are bad for SEO and that's why learning next.js. However I was just thinking that while designing react they should have thought of some optimisation to the issue I have mentioned so looking for a explanation from someone more experienced. Thanks anyways. Happy Coding!!